# How to use the value of key inside ar php foreach loop?

Tags: php

```
$last_msg_id = $this->input->post('last_msg_id');
var_dump($last_msg_id);
if(isset($last_msg_id)){
    foreach($last_msg_id as $key => $value){
        $data['msgs'][$key] = $this->Msg_model->get_msgNew($key, $value);
        var_dump($key);
    }
}
```

The first var dump returns:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2:1' (length=3)
  1 => string '4:1' (length=3)
```

but second returns

```
0, 1
```

I want the second var_dump to return 2 and 4 which are the original keys.

**UPDATE**:

Ok, from comments below is see that propablly the problem is in the way I store the values in JS:

```
var last_msg_id = [];
last_msg_id.unshift(con_idf + ':1');
last_msg_id.unshift(con_idf + ':1');
```

where `con_idf` is 2 and 4 in example that I want to use.

How should I create array in JS so that I could use the same php loop with my desired result of getting 2 and 4 as $key?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. If you want `2` or `4` work with `$value`, not with `$key`

Comment: It's correct. Array keys for $last_msg_id are 0 and 1. '2:1' is value of an element. If you want to get 2 & 4 you got to use $foo = explode(':', $value); then $foo[0] will returns 2 and 4 for these array elements. Or in this exact case can be also intval($value);

Comment: Ok, I got whats actually the problem. I updated the question with accurate formulated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the second var_dump to return 2 and 4 which are the original
>   keys.

If I understood you correctly, you need resulting array like:

```
key = 2, value = 1
key = 4, value = 1
```

**You can achieve this with different way of populating the array in JS**:

```
var last_msg_id = [];
last_msg_id[con_idf] = '1';//if we assume that you want value=1, not value=':1'
...
```

Then you don't need to change the PHP controller.

**Another aproach** is to leave the JS as it is, and extract all the data you need from the values only. You need to modify the PHP controller:

```
foreach($last_msg_id as $key => $value){
    $modified = explode(':', $value);
    $key=$modified[0]; $value=$modified[1];
    $data['msgs'][$key] = $this->Msg_model->get_msgNew($key, $value);
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash and not an array:

```
var last_msg_id = {};
last_msg_id[con_idf] = con_idf + ':1';
for (var i in last_msg_id) {
    console.log(i + ' = ' + last_msg_id[i]);
}
```